# Displaying subtitles (labels changing text) along with audio using Swift & Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, mobile

I'm trying to display subtitles of a spoken audio along with that audio playing. Although I somehow managed to do this, I feel it's not the way it should have been done and that is why I had to ask for help since I haven't found any similar issue on the internet

Basically, I wanted to display 17 sentences at very specific moments of time and that is why I created the loop using delays, which is presented below this text. These sentences are just a label (**@IBOutlet weak var introDisplay: UILabel!**) placed at the bottom of my View Controller that changes text every time delay. I truly had no better idea and I haven't found any specific AVFoundation function for that other than **currentTime** but it seemed to have no effect when I tried to utilize it. What I created is:

```
    for i in 1...17
            {

                switch i
                {
                case 1:
                    displaySentence.text = "SENTENCE 1"
                case 2:
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.48)
                    {
                        self.introDisplay.text = "SENTENCE 2"
                    }
                case 3:
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.00)
                    {
                    self.introDisplay.text = "SENTENCE 3"
                    }
                case 4:
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 7.00)
                    {
                    self.introDisplay.text = "SENTENCE 4"
                    }
//... and so on up to 17th case and default
```

Now, the thing is that subtitles work all fine until the very end where subtitles start to fail in displaying. One sentence should be displayed at a specific time and instead of that particular sentence the next one is displayed at that time (even though that next one has different delay time set). When I then try to make changes to these delays, either making them latter or earlier, nothing works...

I hope you can understand all that's above and it's not fully mumbo jumbo

Comment: Are all the sentences in 1 audio?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I wasn't clear. Audio is just a record of me saying the 17 sentences. Label changes text every particular time delay and label changes that text not in accordance to audio, just along with it. The label changing its text display is nothing else but these 17 sentences previously written (see the code: sentence 1, sentence 2 etc.) 

And to answer your question, yes, all the sentences spoken are in one audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aleksy-

I think your approach to render different texts after specified intervals is complicated. You are presently doing *DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter* in a tight loop. The OS will optimise such context switch's and hence it will result to dropping of some text rendering.

If its just a matter of rendering different texts after certain intervals try below approach. Here I'm just firing a repeat timer with 1/60 ( generally considered as a good FPS for rendering )interval. Based on the time elapsed interval the relevant text shall be chosen for rendering. Once done make sure that you stop the timer.

```
func stopRendering()->Void
{
    self.renderingTimer?.invalidate()
}

func startRenderingEngine()->Void
{
    let timerStartDate = Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow:0)

    self.renderingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1/60.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    let elapsedTime:Int = Int(abs(timerStartDate.timeIntervalSinceNow))

        switch elapsedTime
        {
            case 1:
                self.introDisplay.text = "SENTENCE 1"
            case 3:
                self.introDisplay.text = "SENTENCE 2"
            case 5:
                self.introDisplay.text = "SENTENCE 3"
            case 8:
                self.introDisplay.text = "SENTENCE 4"
            case 12:
                self.introDisplay.text = "SENTENCE 4"
            case 15:
                self.introDisplay.text = "SENTENCE 5"
            default:
                if(elapsedTime>16)
                {
                    self.introDisplay.text = "Finished rendering !"
                    self.stopRendering()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: The context switching is avoided here as the timer's are fired in main thread.*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Too bad my reputations points don't allow me to score your post